# Automating minimum scale (of volume for said part) for fine detailed objects are going to be 3d printed

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural, 3d-printing

I am working on a project in Blender which is fairly simple, using sappling tree gen, solidify and bevel to create a printable 3d sculpture.

One thing I'm unable to solve using the above features is that inevitably I can't without making the model look completely alien achieve scaling of minimum 1-2mm<sup>3</sup> for branches apart from with a ridiculous amount of manual sculpting which often leads to failure. (This is on my part for not being good enough with the tooling to solve some of blenders slightly more difficult non-manifold edge issues).

Is there a way to programatically/procedurallly/use tooling to effective scale any part of the model that is below x mm in width, height or depth.

I know I should probably be quiet and get on with the hard work but I can see this kind of technique being very useful for various miniature scale models (4-10cmm xyz with extremely fine details.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I want to say using simulation nodes or you can have a look at selections based on values https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTFD1fnTVtk

Comment: Thankyou, this has helped me get started. Think I'm on the right track but have a lot to learn about geometry nodes.